# How to extract multiple items from a single loop and fill multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to pull multiple items (XML nodes) from this Zillow URL. My code contains a for each loop that can only pull a single node (item) on each loop , but I need to fill other columns with available data on the URL

I've tried adding a variable to extract this node, but after pulling some data I always end up with the "Run-Time Error '91': Object Variable or With Block Variable Not Set"

Here is a working VBA code to pull a single item

```
 URLs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("URLLIST").Range("B4:B" & URLCount).Value



Set xmlDocument = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
xmlDocument.async = False
' xmlDocument.validateOnParse = False

For i = LBound(URLs, 1) To UBound(URLs, 1)
    xmlDocument.Load URLs(i, 1)
    Set nodeId = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//response/results/result/zestimate/amount")
    Set nodeId2 = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//response/results/result/finishedSqFt")


    If Not nodeId Is Nothing Then
    With Sheets("ZILLOW DATA")
        NextRow = .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("E" & NextRow).Value = nodeId.Text

    End With

Else
    With Sheets("ZILLOW DATA")
        NextRow = .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("E" & NextRow).Value = "N/A"

    End With

    End If
Set nodeId = Nothing: Set nodeId2 = Nothing
Next
```

And here is a screenshot of some items I want to pull

[image]

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: The code I have attached works just fine for a to pull a single item. But if I declare a new variable as "NextRow2" and add the request here      -  " With Sheets("ZILLOW DATA")
        NextRow = .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("E" & NextRow).Value = nodeId.Text
        .Range("F" & NextRow2).Value = nodeId2.Text
    End With  "       ---   I get the error described earlier

Comment: Can you provide us with a list of url's as well?  Will make it easier to test an answer with.  Please add them to your question.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are doing a `Select` instead of `Get`?

Comment: URL list contains API key. You can get a FREE API key from Zillow. But here's what the URL look like - "http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDeepSearchResults.htm?zws-id=ENTER YOUR ZWS-ID HERE &address=776+Cady+Way+&citystatezip=Atlanta+GA+30312

Comment: Zac, with respect to my reason for using a Select instead of Get, there is no special reason for that. Do you suggest I try "Get"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me ...

```
Public Sub ExtractXml()
    Dim objHttp As XMLHTTP60, objXml As DOMDocument60, strUrl As String
    Dim objDict As Scripting.Dictionary, strValue As String, lngWriteRow As Long
    Dim objCell As Range

    Set objHttp = New XMLHTTP60
    Set objXml = New DOMDocument60

    Set objDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    objDict.Add "//amount", "A"
    objDict.Add "//finishedSqFt", "B"
    objDict.Add "//bathrooms", "C"
    objDict.Add "//bedrooms", "D"

    For Each objCell In Worksheets("URLLIST").Range("B4:B500")
        strUrl = objCell.Text

        If strUrl <> "" Then
            With objHttp
                .Open "GET", strUrl, False
                .send
            End With

            If objXml.LoadXML(objHttp.responseText) Then
                On Error Resume Next

                lngWriteRow = lngWriteRow + 1

                For i = 0 To objDict.Count - 1
                    Err.Clear

                    strValue = objXml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(CStr(objDict.Keys(i))).Text

                    If Err.Description <> "" Then
                        strValue = "Not Found"
                    End If

                    Sheet1.Range(CStr(objDict.Items(i) & lngWriteRow)) = strValue
                Next

                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

... add **Scripting.Dictionary** as a reference and then loop through dynamically extracting your required nodes and their inner text values.  `lngWriteRow` is the row that will increment each time you query a property.

`objDict` is where you need to add your `XPath` query and then the item in the dictionary is the associated column you want to write it out to.

Adapt that to fit your URL list and then increment lngWriteRow each time you make a new query.

If a node is not found, then it will show ...

> Not Found

... in the corresponding field.

To be honest, not sure if that helps or not but worked for me.  I'd need more URL's to test thoroughly with though.

Comment: Thanks for this. Considering that your variable strUrl is declared as a string, how do I add this values to that variable so the for each loop can repeat the process. For now, it works with pulling all the items but doesn't go to the next row    This is where my URL list is located -  Worksheets("URLLIST").Range("B4:B500").Value

Comment: @SmithO. added the loop around the main section.  You may want to add a line of code to check to make sure strUrl <> "" if your loop extends beyond the end of your url range or there is a blank in there somewhere.

Comment: Almost done! Just one minor issue left. When it loops to the end of the URL list or to any point where there is a blank cell in the list it will trigger a Run time error - "The parameter is incorrect". I'll appreciate your help on this issue

Comment: @SmithO. yeah, that's what I was saying before, just add an if statement to check strUrl and whether it equals blank or not.  Answer updated.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot